# Gulp.js get filename from .src()

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I'm trying to use `gulp-proceesshtml` (https://github.com/julien/gulp-processhtml) to remove some unwanted code in my build version, the problem is that the task requires a filename to be given.

`gulp.src('test.html').pipe(processhtml('test.html'));`

But I can't figure out how this would work when I'm processing all HTML files in a folder

`gulp.src('*.html).pipe(processhtml('filename here'));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<del>Personally, it sounds like that's the wrong plugin for what you are trying to accomplish.</del> **See below**.

However, because it's not clear what you are using it for, you can be able to use [`node-glob`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/glob) to process each file one-by-one:

```
var glob = require('glob')
    // you also need event-stream for merging the streams
    es = require('event-stream');

gulp.task('myTask', function() {
    var files = glob.sync('*.html'),
        streams;
    streams = files.map(function(file) {
                // add the *base* option if your files are stored in
                // multiple subdirectories
        return gulp.src(file, {base: 'relative/base/path'})
                // may need require('path').filename(file)
                .pipe(processhtml(file));
    });

    return es.merge.apply(es, streams);
});
```

This will create a single asynchronous stream out of every file that matches your initial pattern.

---

For simply removing some text from your files, you can use [`gulp-replace`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-replace/), like so:

```
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.src('*.html')
   // replaces all text between
   // <!-- remove-this --> and <!-- /remove-this -->
   .pipe(replace(/<!--\s*remove-this\s*-->[\s\S]*?<!--\s*\/remove-this\s*-->/g, ''));
```

Comment: I'm only using it because it allows me to have some code removed when building `<!-- build:remove-->Dev code<!-- /build -->`. If there is any other plugin, happy to use that

Comment: It would probably be smarter to *add* code during development.  This would be less error-prone (ie: You couldn't accidentally deploy dev code to your server.)  Is the code custom, or just the livereload snippet?  Without knowing exactly what it is, it's hard to make a recommendation.

Comment: With my current development stack this is the best way to do it, there are some things I want to see locally, but not in my actual build. And the code that's being executed locally is just a small redirect for clients so they don't stumble upon a broken page. So the only thing I need to have is something that is able to remove a few lines of javascript from an HTML file.

Comment: What about using [`gulp-replace`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-replace/): `.pipe(replace(/<-- remove-this -->[\s\S]*<-- \/remove-this -->/g, ''))`.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is old, but for a shorter solution you can use [gulp-tap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tap), something like this:

```
.pipe(tap(function(file, t) {
    console.log(file.path);
 }))
```

if you need to use the filename in other step of the pipe you can store it in a variable and use it for next step.